# Delegating attributes to those of a OneToOneField in Django

Tags: python, django

I have a model `UserGuide` which extends Django's `User` model through a one-to-one relationship. I would like to make it such that for an instance `lucy_guide`, a call to an attribute `lucy_guide.first_name` will return `luyy_guide.user.first_name` (and similar for `last_name`). Here is my first pass at implementing this:

```
class LucyGuide(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        if attr in ['first_name', 'last_name'] and self.user:
            return getattr(self.user, attr)
        return super().__getattr__(attr)
```

Does this look OK? I know Django can behave differently from 'regular Python' due to its use of metaclasses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you just define explicit properties on your model rather than messing around with `__getattr__`:

```
class LucyGuide(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    @property
    def first_name(self)
        return self.user.first_name

    @property
    def last_name(self)
        return self.user.last_name
```

Which you will then be able to access with `lucy_guide.first_name` and `lucy_guide.last_name`.

Comment: In general, there might be more than two fields I'd like to 'delegate' and this approach would lead to code repetition. Is there anything wrong with the `__getattr__()` method? It seems to work...

Comment: No, there's nothing wrong with it - just that "explicit is better than implicit" is one of the mantras in Python. If you need to support arbitrary fields then your original approach is fine IMO.